# VirtualBox with bridged network won't started [VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND]

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a problem with starting my virtual machine (with WinXP on it) with bridged network. On normal NAT connection everything went fine.

I searched a litte bit around and found possible soulutions but in every "solution" that I found was something with "Enable < VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver >" but on my machine this is already enabled and it don't work.

### Specs of my machine

- CPU: [Intel® Core™ i5-7600K Processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/97144/Intel-Core-i5-7600K-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-4_20-GHz) (virtualization enabled)
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
- RAM: 2x 8GB
- OS: Windows 10 64-bit (currently in use) & Linux Mint 18.2
- Network card: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet

### Screenshots

[image: Windows network configuration]

[image: VM network configuration]

[image: Error on launch]

### Log

```
VirtualBox VM 5.2.12 r122591 win.amd64 (May  9 2018 10:42:46) release log
00:00:04.102217 Log opened 2018-05-23T16:47:05.787120600Z
00:00:04.102218 Build Type: release
00:00:04.102220 OS Product: Windows 10
00:00:04.102221 OS Release: 10.0.16299
00:00:04.102222 OS Service Pack: 
00:00:04.135313 DMI Product Name: MS-7977
00:00:04.138033 DMI Product Version: 1.0
00:00:04.138041 Host RAM: 16344MB (15.9GB) total, 11158MB (10.8GB) available
00:00:04.138043 Executable: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
00:00:04.138044 Process ID: 3760
00:00:04.138044 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:04.139500 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:04.139558   None installed!
00:00:04.140255 Console: Machine state changed to 'Starting'
00:00:04.274430 Qt version: 5.6.2
...
00:00:05.559413 VD: Opening the disk took 339968 ns
00:00:05.559551 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#0: disk, PCHS=16383/16/63, total number of sectors 20971520
00:00:05.559562 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#1: no unit
00:00:05.559597 DrvVD: Flushes will be ignored
00:00:05.559603 DrvVD: Async flushes will be passed to the disk
00:00:05.559664 VD: Opening the disk took 55052 ns
00:00:05.559838 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#2: CD/DVD, total number of sectors 28309, passthrough disabled
00:00:05.559848 PIIX3 ATA: LUN#3: no unit
00:00:05.559887 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: finished processing RESET
00:00:05.559903 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#1: finished processing RESET
00:00:05.560077 IntNet#0: szNetwork={HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter} enmTrunkType=3 szTrunk={\DEVICE\{BFB9A6EF-150D-4916-8379-188DAD594137}} fFlags=0x8000 cbRecv=325632 cbSend=196608 fIgnoreConnectFailure=false
00:00:05.560123 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-5.2\src\VBox\Devices\Network\DrvIntNet.cpp(1768) int __cdecl drvR3IntNetConstruct(struct PDMDRVINS *,struct CFGMNODE *,unsigned int); rc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND
00:00:05.560213 VMSetError: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter'
00:00:05.560247 PDM: Failed to construct 'pcnet'/0! VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND (-3600) - The networking interface to filter was not found.
00:00:05.633348 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:05.633674 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:05.756661 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
00:00:06.256859 GUI: Aborting startup due to power up progress issue detected...
00:00:06.635508 OpenGL Error: Render SPU: (MakeCurrent) failed to make 0xb401123a, 0x10000 current with 0x6 error.
00:00:06.639233 crUtil DLL unloaded.
```

### What I did

After I noticed that my VM not start, I changed the mode to "Host-only adapter" and created new adapter under *File -> Host Network Manager*. This worked but I had no internet connection. So, I decided to re-install virtualbox, result: No change.

Comment: Select a physical ethernet Intel I219-V/Killer E2400 under "Name:" when you use Bridged Adapter. Make sure "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver" is enabled in the physical ethernet you are using. Bridging to VBox Host-Only Adapter is nonsense...

Comment: @guest-vm Got BSOD with error code: "IRQL_UNEXPECTED_VALUE". [Dump](https://i.imgur.com/I9EOg2L.png) and [Network settings](https://i.imgur.com/GCqhu5F.png)

Comment: See [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16229) (especially the last comment).

Comment: @guest-vm Thanks, now it works ^^.

Comment: btw please use **Intel PRO/1000 T Server** (1 Gbps) instead of **PCNet PCI II** (10 Mbps).

Comment: @guest-vm Yeah, I choosed "PCnet2" because I thougt that I have no internet connection because windows xp didn't detect "Intel PRO/1000 T Server". But now everything works ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to choose as adapter my own network card.

In my case I have a "Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet" and had to disable "Killer Bandwidth Control" in *windows network connections* for my network card to prevent a BSOD on start. Now everything is fine.